# Replaced Safe-T-Beam on Genie Garage door opener, now I have no power

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

I replaced the Safe-T-Beam sensors on my garage door opener because of periodic issues with the door not closing. Now I have no power from the unit (SilentMax 1000). I tested the outlet and it has power, but I can't get any of the buttons on the unit to work, and I can't even get the emitter to blink intermittently showing that it's out of line. I rewired to the old sensors and the same behavior.

All of my wire connections seem safe and connected, but I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

Comment: Do you have the instruction manual or have you tried to find it online. Is there a reset button on the unit.

Comment: Did you turn the power off when making the change. Connect the wiring according to schematics?

Comment: Yes. I unplugged the unit and only replaced the sensors, not the wiring. There’s no power at the main unit, but the outlet does have power.

Comment: "*There’s no power at the main unit, but the outlet does have power*" can you elaborate on that.

Comment: I mean that the outlet into which the opener has power, but the unit itself does not illuminate any of the LEDs when buttons are pushed on it